# Removing element from an array

Tags: javascript

```
function removeItem(){
    for(i=0;i<rowData.length;i++){
        if(rowData[i].title = 'First Name'){
            rowData.splice(i,1);
            break;
        }
}
```

This does not delete the object whose has a title property 'First Name' instead deletes the last added object to the array.

Comment: Did u try using == to compare strings instead of = ?

Comment: If you really have `=` in your code, it should actually delete the first element....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `==` operator instead of `=` in the **if** condition.`=` is for assignment and not for comparing.

Edit 1: For more info follow [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Answer (score 1):

On line three you have a typo. Instead of `=`, it should say `==`